# Combining two fast indexed queries makes the result slow

Tags: mysql

I have two tables A and B.

Table A

```
guid | username
---------------
  A  |  name1
  B  |  name2
  C  |  name3
```

With index

```
+--------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tableA |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | guid         | A         |     2242900 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Table B

```
guidA | guidB
-------------
  A   |   C
  B   |   C
```

With index

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tableB   |          1 | guidA_idx           |            1 | userid      | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableB   |          1 | guidB_idx           |            1 | userid      | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

What I want is to make a query where given **`guidB`** I fetch the **`username`** of the corresponding **`guidA`**

When selecting only from Table A its fast..

```
select guid from tableA where guid IN ('A', 'B');
```

With DESC

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableA  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 66      | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Selecting from Table B is fast too...(it only has three rows so no index is used)

```
select guidA from tableB where guidB = 'C';
```

DESC

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys| key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableB | ALL  | guidB_idx    | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

However! If I do

```
select guid, username from tableA where guid IN (select guidA from tableB where guidB = 'C');
```

I get the correct result but the query is slow since the index on guid in tableA is never used.

DESC

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys       | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                                   |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableA | ALL  | NULL                | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2242900 | NULL                                                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableB | ALL  | guidA_idx,guidB_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       3 | Using where; FirstMatch(tableA); Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since, as you can see, it does a full table scan. I read somewhere that using `WHERE IN (subquery)` has optimization issues but rewriting the query as a **`LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, or INNER JOIN`** didnt give a different result. I always get a full table scan on `tableA`. I get the correct result each time.

The joins...

```
select a.guid, a.username from tableA a left join tableB b on b.guidA = a.guid where b.guidB = 'C';
select a.guid, a.username from tableA a right join tableB b on a.guid = b.guidA where b.guidB = 'C';
select a.guid, a.username from tableA a inner join tableB b on b.guidA = a.guid where b.guidB = 'C';
```

My MySQL version is **Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28, for Win64 (x86_64)**

Comment: Is you `tableA.guid` a `VARCHAR`, a `TEXT` or a `INT`?

Comment: VARCHAR(64) @Xenos

Comment: And is the tableB using the exact same type (same `VARCHAR(64)` and same `collation`)? Otherwise, index won't be usable.

Comment: Ahh thats the problem! Thanks alot. The tables had different collations.

Comment: Okay, I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns must have the same type and collation.

Different collation or different type will avoid the usage of any index.